# How to apply pipe to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is any way to apply pipe operator to the dictionary object like pandas dataframe.

With pandas dataframe we can do below steps:

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0], 'B' : [1]})
dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [0], 'D' : [1]})
chose = 'something'

((dat1 if chose == 'something' else dat2)
   .pipe(lambda x : x.assign(col_new = lambda z : 'some_value'))
)
```

Similarly now let's say we have a dictionary:

```
dat1 = {'A' : [0], 'B' : [1]}
dat2 = {'C' : [0], 'D' : [1]}
chose = 'something'

((dat1 if chose == 'something' else dat2)
   .pipe(lambda x : x['A'])
)
```

But now I get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pipe'
```

Is there any way to apply pipe like pandas to dictionary object?

Comment: that is not an operator, that is a method on `pandas.Dataframe`. And as you clearly demonstrated, `dict` objects have no such method

Comment: As an aside, both of these uses of `.pipe` are unnecessary... you are using them to call *methods* on the dataframe, so you can just remove the `.pipe` and apply them directly...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just wanted to provide some example on what I intend to do. I understand that there is no method like `pipe` for `dict`, but purpose of this post is ask if there is similar approach can be followed i.e. `chain rule`

Comment: So for example the first one could just be `(dat1 if chose == 'something' else dat2).assign(col_new = 'some_value')`

Comment: chain rule? What does this have to do with the chain rule? In any case, no, no there isn't in `dict`. You can *implement* it yourself if you want. Generic pipe-like libraries probably exist as well.

Comment: Basically, what I wish to perform is : I have multiple `dict` objects and chose one of them based on some criteria. Then continue with that for subsequent calculations. I could first create a new object (let name it `new_dict`) with `if-else` condition etc. and then continue with  `new_dict` for subsequent calculation. But I want to avoid this route as it requires to create a new object

Comment: "But I want to avoid this route as it requires to create a new object" it does not. Why don't you ask about what you are *actually* trying to accomplish. All `.pipe` let's you do with `pandas.DataFrame` obejcts is avoid nested parentheses. It doesn't let you avoid creating intermediate objects. What you are describing doesn't even sound like something you would use a pipe-like operator for. You should add more details, a [mcve], of what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Indeed, this is not a native way. But implementing such a generic class on your own should be quite straightforward. Also, there is a package for functional programming, it's called `returns`. Check the [`Pipelines section`](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pipeline.html#), it does a similar thing to what you need.

Comment: So, for your example, `(dat1 if chose == 'something' else dat2)['A']` would just work. You don't even need a pipe-like functionality (which is more of an issue of syntax, it doesn't really *add* any capabilities)

Comment: mmm if what you want is to pick a value from among multiple dict, the [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) can help you with that

Comment: https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pipes allows to achieve somewhat similar behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate the "R-like" behaviour (a function from any class to any other class), you can create a thin wrapper around any value:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Callable

A = TypeVar("A")
B = TypeVar("B")


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Box(Generic[A]):
    value: A

    def pipe(self, fn: Callable[[A], B]) -> "Box[B]":
        return Box(fn(self.value))
```

Test-drive:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = (
        Box({"a": 2, "b": 1})
        .pipe(lambda d: d["a"])
        .pipe(lambda a: a * 10)
        .pipe(str)
        .pipe(lambda s: f"Value={s}")
    )
    print(b, b.value, type(b))
```

The output:

```
Box(value='Value=20') Value=20 <class '__main__.Box'>
```

In general, it is nothing more than a classical `map` function from the functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, you can directly access the dictionary key without lambda:

```
dat1 = {'A' : [0], 'B' : [1]}
dat2 = {'C' : [2], 'D' : [3]}
chose = 'something'

(dat1 if chose == 'something' else dat2).get('A')
```

Output: `[0]`

Comment: I suspect the OP is trying to accomplish something else. Also, I would use indexing `['A']` just to demonstrate the equivalence.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is probably correct, but then OP should provide a meaningful example to ensure not falling into a XY problem